# Drop multiple duplicated columns after left join w/ dataframes?

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark-sql

I'm working on a script using Pyspark and Spark SQL. However, after running a `LEFT-JOIN` on my `base_df` and `inc_df` dateframes,  all of my columns were duplicated.

I've figured out why the columns were duplicated, but I'm now receiving `type errors` while trying to `DROP` those duplicated columns.

I've tried this solution as well.... `a.join(b, 'id')`

Here's part of my code below..

```
''' uc_df = (base_df

         .join(inc_df,

               (inc_df.src_sys_id == base_df.src_sys_id) & (inc_df.fleet_acct_nbr == base_df.fleet_acct_nbr),

               "left_outer")

         .filter(inc_df.src_sys_id.isNull())

         .drop(base_df.region_cd,

               base_df.fleet_acct_exctv_cd,

               base_df.fleet_acct_nbr,

               base_df.fleet_acct_exctv_nm,

               base_df.fleet_acct_exctv_first_nm,

               base_df.fleet_acct_exctv_last_nm,

               base_df.fleet_acct_exctv_mid_nm,

               base_df.fleet_acct_nm,

               base_df.meas_cnt,

               base_df.dw_anom_flg,

               base_df.dw_mod_ts,

               base_df.src_sys_iud_cd,

               base_df.dw_job_id)

       

        )
```

I received the following error:

```
Type Error: Each column in the param list should be a string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to drop anything. Rather you can make use of `select` and aliasing the dataframes as below -

```
df1.alias("a").join(df2.alias("b"), df1["key"] == df2["key"], 'inner').select("a.*").show()
```

Replace the values corresponding to yours